# MySQL Procedurde within if Statement?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, procedure

is it possible, to call a procedure within a IF Statement?

```
IF(1=1, call GetAllFemiFAUFCount(1005876054),'')
```

many thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: An easy one to test - and you get a syntax error if you try , you can invoke function though.

Comment: But a error occurs: SQL Fehler (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(1=1, call GetAllFemiFAUFCount(1005876054),'')' at line 1

Comment: Your conclusion should be that you cannot call a procedure from an if statement

Comment: @RahulChawla: do you have correct syntax to call the proc?